Power BI :: last day makes the line drop
After endless fight with DAX I finally arrived to have a Forecast. Noice.
However there is a drop in the Line Chart that I would like to remove. That drop is caused by the date of today:

That drop is because the data are refreshed daily and therefore, I suppose, there must be blanks.
This is the code:
Forecast = 
VAR LastDayDate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('cost-management-export'[date]),
        REMOVEFILTERS()
    )
VAR Actuals = 'Sumeru Measure Table'[Switch Currency]
VAR FutureForecast = 
    CALCULATE(
        [Cost Forecasting],
        //[Cost Last Year],
         KEEPFILTERS('Calendar'[Date] > LastDayDate)
    )

VAR Result = FutureForecast + Actuals 

RETURN
    Result

How can I remove the last 1-2 days?
I tried to use DAYADD but no joy
UPDATE: Here the files:

Forecast.pbix
Forecast.xlsx


Was this solved?

Sorry Davide, this was not solved.

How about this?
Update:
Forecast = 
VAR LastDayDate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Export'[date]),
        REMOVEFILTERS() 
    ) 
VAR Actuals = SUM('Export'[costInBillingCurrency])
VAR FutureForecast = 
    CALCULATE(
        [Cost Forecasting],
        //[Cost Last Year],
         KEEPFILTERS('Calendar'[Date] >= LastDayDate )
    )

VAR Result = FutureForecast + Actuals 

RETURN
  IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date]) = LastDayDate, Result - Actuals,  Result)

You can get rid of the last day of actuals in the same way if you don't want to see the dip.


Thank you David, not sure why but it goes upside down: https://snipboard.io/yB3CpU.jpg

Can you send a .pbix?

I'll update now
